# Angular2 Routing - Passing data from parent component to a sub-child component

Tags: javascript, routes, angular

I am trying to pass a simple string object from a parent component to a sub-child component. I have tried doing it the following way:

**parent.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {ChildCmp} from "./child";
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template:`
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ParentCmp{
    public data = "Some data from parent.";
    constructor (private _router:Router){
        var config = [];
        if(!this._router.registry.hasRoute("Child",ParentCmp))
            config.push({path: "/child/...",component:ChildCmp,name: 'Child',useAsDefault:true, data: {"data": this.data}});

        this._router.config(config);
    }
}

bootstrap(ParentCmp,[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

**child.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteData,Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {SubChildCmp} from "./sub_child";

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([

])
export class ChildCmp{
    public data:Object;
    constructor(private _data:RouteData,private _router:Router){

        this.data = this._data.get("data");

        var config = [];
        if(!this._router.registry.hasRoute("SubChild",ChildCmp))
            config.push({path:"/sub_child",component: SubChildCmp,name:"SubChild", useAsDefault:true, data:{"data":this.data}});

        this._router.config(config);
    }
}
```

**sub_child.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: "sub-child",
    template: `Data from parent is -->
    {{data}}
    `
})
export class SubChildCmp{
    public data:Object;

    constructor(private _data:RouteData){

        this.data = this._data.get("data");
    }
}
```

But I am getting a blank page. It looks like the routing configuration in `child.ts` is not being configured properly. How can I achieve this? I just want to pass some data from `parent` component to `sub-child` component. I re-produced the problem [here on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TpaNyNwG1GbYKCjVaV6x?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually a service is used for this use case

```
@Injectable
export class SharedData {
  data;
}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [SharedData],
    template:`
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ParentCmp{
    public data = "Some data from parent.";
    constructor (private _router:Router, private _sharedData:SharedData){
        var config = [];
        if(!this._router.registry.hasRoute("Child",ParentCmp))
            _sharedData.data = this.data;
        }
    }
}
```

```
export class SubChildCmp{
    public data:Object;

    constructor(_sharedData:SharedData){

        this.data = _sharedData.data;
    }
}
```

Using `Observable` or `BehaviorSubject` with `subscribe()` might be necessary if there are timing issues, for example when `SubChildCmp` reads the value before the `ParentCmp` has set it.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.